# Copy a directory from container to host

Tags: docker

I have saved a folder called "ec2-user" in an image. And I can easily extract one of the files...

```
docker run  -it shantanuo/bkup sh

docker exec -it e7611fc860a6 sh -c " cat /tmp/ec2-user/t1.txt" > t1.txt
```

This works as expected. But I do not know how to copy the entire directory "ec2-user" that is around 8 GB

In other words I am using docker as backup device. This is different that application deployment, but I will like to know if this is OK.

Comment: try this: docker cp.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: the title of this question is misleading - you're not copying from an image in the question and the accepted answer is also not copying from an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the name of your file and its size (8GB) I guess you're doing a database backup?

Since you want to `copy` the entire directory and it is relatively big, why not consider compressing the backup directory to a single file and then just do

`docker cp my_container:/tmp/bkup/abc.xz .`

To compress your backup you can use the `xz` utility.

**Example:**
`shantanuo/bkup | xz -8 > /tmp/bkup.xz`